# Fade in / Fade out "Show More" button text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello everyone I have a problem. How can I Fade in (and out) the text that appears when pressing the button "show more". I have searched and found this piece of code from w3school, I tried to implement it in my own code but I need help with it any suggestions?

Found piece of code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".btn1").click(function() {
        $("p").fadeOut()
      });
      $(".btn2").click(function() {
        $("p").fadeIn();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  <button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
  <button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleTextPersonal() {
  if (status == "less") {
    document.getElementById("showMorePersonal").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toggleButtonPersonal").innerHTML = "Show Less <i class='fas fa-caret-up'></i>";
    status = "more";
  } else if (status == "more") {
    document.getElementById("showMorePersonal").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("toggleButtonPersonal").innerHTML = "Show More <i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i>";
    status = "less"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="showMorePersonal" style="display: none;">
    test
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="toggleButtonPersonal" onclick="toggleTextPersonal();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

  <div id="textArea" style="display: none;">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `jQuery` file and use `$("#showMorePersonal").fadeIn();` and `$("#showMorePersonal").fadeOut();` as mentioned in snippet.

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleTextPersonal()


{
    
    if (status == "less") {
        $("#showMorePersonal").fadeIn();
      document.getElementById("toggleButtonPersonal").innerHTML = "Show Less <i class='fas fa-caret-up'></i>";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
         $("#showMorePersonal").fadeOut();
       document.getElementById("toggleButtonPersonal").innerHTML = "Show More <i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i>";

        status = "less"
    }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="showMorePersonal" style="display: none;">
    test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButtonPersonal" onclick="toggleTextPersonal();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;"> 

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery way to do this. Please, read the comment:

```js
var showMorePersonal = $('#showMorePersonal');
var toggleButtonPersonal = $('#toggleButtonPersonal');

toggleButtonPersonal.on('click', function() {
  // check if `showMorePersonal` div is visible. If so, fadeOut it and replace the text
  if (showMorePersonal.is(':visible')) {
    toggleButtonPersonal.html('Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>');
    showMorePersonal.fadeOut();
  } else {
    toggleButtonPersonal.html('Show Less <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>');
    showMorePersonal.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="showMorePersonal" style="display: none;">
  test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButtonPersonal">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

Read more about:

- [`visible-selector`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
- [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)
- [`on` event listener](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

If anything is not clear, let me know.